# Corda - In a Corda network, how do participating companies handle customer interaction and identities on the ledger?

Tags: corda

If a group of companies want to create a loyalty token scheme via a Corda network, how do they enable customers to be able to receive or spend loyalty tokens via any of the participating company channels?

For example, Alice earns 100 tokens from Company X's shopping app for being a loyal customer. The record of Alice's balance is captured on the Corda ledger via Company X's Corda node. Alice then wants to spend these tokens on Company Y's shopping app.

How is Alice identified on the Corda network?
How can this be achieved so that only Alice has the power to spend her tokens (i.e. the participating companies cannot edit her balance without her consent.)?

I'm thinking this could be achieved if customers had their own key pair and needed their private key to transact. Is this currently possible on Corda or is it on the roadmap?

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is now possible with [accounts-sdk](https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/docs.md) released with Corda 4.3.
So you could now have multiple companies host their customers on their nodes as accounts and have loyalty tokens issued to them. So accounts feature can be integrated with tokens feature.

To your question regarding, How can this be achieved so that only Alice has the power to spend her tokens, tokens sdk makes sure that only the current holder/owner of the token has the right to spend the tokens.

Your last question
I'm thinking this could be achieved if customers had their own key pair and needed their private key to transact. Is this currently possible on Corda or is it on the roadmap?
As I mentioned above that the companies can have their customers represented as accounts on their nodes. But please note that as of now, accounts are not true identities, i.e. they do not have any certificate issued by the doorman. They use anonymous identities to transact with each other. But yes, there is a plan where accounts will be able to move these key pairs outside of the node and effectively own their own private keys.